object declared in lwc getter is proxy object
I am trying to create an object in a getter for a lwc. For some reason when I declare the object, it is proxy object and does not retain any of the properties that I assign to it.
I am really struggling with this one. I declare the result object let result = new Object();
but when I log it it is a proxy object and is always empty, even after being assigned values in the for loop. I have tried the code in console and it works, assume it is something to do with the lwc system. let result = {};doesn't work either.
I am trying to transform a soql query to a nested object and then array of objects for my table, I'm not sure if it is the best approach to do it in a getter? Any advice on the approach would also be appreciated. Thanks!
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/PermissionSetEditorController.getData';

export default class PermissionSetTable extends LightningElement {

  @wire(getData) theData;

  get tabledata() {

    const uniqueFields = new Set();
    console.log("uf inital", uniqueFields);
    const uniquePermissionSetNames = new Set();
    let result = new Object();
    console.log(result);
    if (this.theData && this.theData.data) {

      // Derive uniqueFields
      this.theData.data.forEach(item => {
        uniqueFields.add(item.Field)
      });
      console.log('uf', uniqueFields);

      // Derive uniquePermissionSetNames
      this.theData.data.forEach(item => {
        uniquePermissionSetNames.add(item.PermissionSetName)
      });
      console.log('uniquePermSetNames', uniquePermissionSetNames);
      
      // set up nested object structure
      console.log('ufsize', uniqueFields.size);
      console.log("result before loop", result);
      if (uniqueFields.size > 0) {
        uniqueFields.forEach(field => {
          // console.log('field', field);
          result[field] = {};
          //result[field] = {};
          //console.log("in loop", result);
          // uniquePermissionSetNames.forEach(permissionSetName => {
          //   result[field][permissionSetName] = '';
          //});
        });
        console.log('result', result.size);
      }
    }
    return Array.from(uniqueFields);
  }

  get responseReceived () {
    if (this.theData) {
      return true
    }
    false
  }
}

